# Null Pointer exception when I try to add a "drawer toggle" in action bar activity with tabs

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

In my android project i have a Activity with actionbar that has 2 tabs, i also add a drawer menu but, when I try to setup the app icon to a toggle button for open the drawer, I get a Nullpointexception. Here is my code:

```
public class PaginaPrincipalActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<TelaPrincipalDrawerItens> navDrawerItems;
private DrawerPrincipalAdapter adapter;

ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2;
Fragment fragmentTab1 = new TabFragmentPrincipal();
Fragment fragmentTab2 = new TabEmTransporte();


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_principal_activity);



    navDrawerItems = (ArrayList<TelaPrincipalDrawerItens>) createDrawerItens();
    //setando drawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.layout.telaprincipal_drawer);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    adapter = new DrawerPrincipalAdapter(this, R.layout.telaprincipal_item_drawer, navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Handle your other action bar items...


    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    tab1 = getActionBar().newTab().setText("Principal");
    tab2 = getActionBar().newTab().setText("Em Transporte");

    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab1));
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab2));

    getActionBar().addTab(tab1);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab2);


    //Try to add drawertoggle 
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
            ){
        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };

 // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);     

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
      //  displayView(0);
    }


}

 @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.receber_os_menu, menu);


    return true;

}

public List createDrawerItens(){

    List l = new ArrayList();
    l.add( new TelaPrincipalDrawerItens("Senor Abravanel","001.415.333-987", R.drawable.ic_maoe, false));
    l.add( new TelaPrincipalDrawerItens("Configuações",R.drawable.ic_action_settings, false));
    l.add( new TelaPrincipalDrawerItens("Upload de Dados",R.drawable.ic_action_upload, false));
    l.add( new TelaPrincipalDrawerItens("Download de Dados",R.drawable.ic_action_download, false));
    l.add( new TelaPrincipalDrawerItens("Sair",R.drawable.ic_sair, false));

    return l;
}

}
```

And here is my logCat output:

```
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661): Process: com.ass.app.delivermobile,PID:2661
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{com.ass.app.delivermobile/com.ass.app.delivermobile.GUI.activities.PaginaPrincipalActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at com.ass.app.delivermobile.GUI.activities.PaginaPrincipalActivity.onCreate(PaginaPrincipalActivity.java:110)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-25 13:35:30.017: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     ... 11 more
```

Please, if someone can please help me I will be extremely grateful!

Comment: Hi, could you please help us a bit and point out line 110 from PaginaPrincipalActivity class?

Comment: Of course! here's  the line:

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

Comment: mDrawerLayout is not null?

Comment: @jackgris, in this line : " mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.layout.telaprincipal_drawer); " mDrawerLayout get a reference to a layout that has a drawer.

Comment: I know, you should test, if those two objects were successfully created. If this is line 100 mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); Place an breackpoint in this line and look that shows you.

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-navigationdrawer/) for Material Navigation bar and this [link](http://androhub.com/android-material-design-tabs-using-tablayout/) for Material Tabs.